# Getting error with encoded GET request

Tags: javascript, java, spring, url-encoding, datatables-1.10

I am trying to do a `GET` call to reload the data table.

I am encoding the following dates and sending them **2015/11/01 18:38** and **2015/11/09 18:38** as a path variable.

```
2015/11/01 18:38 -> encoded -> 2015%2F11%2F01%2018%3A38 
2015/11/09 18:38 -> encoded -> 2015%2F11%2F09%2018%3A38
```

I am getting the error:

```
http://localhost:8880/myapp/getAlertFilterHistory/2015%2F11%2F01%2018%3A38/2015%2F11%2F09%2018%3A38/?_=1448024862539
400 Bad Request 76ms jquery.min.js (line 4)
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:8880/myapp/getAlertFilterHistory/2015%2F11%2F01%2018%3A38/2015%2F11%2F09%2018%3A38/?_=1448024862539"
```

But if I use the following URL it works fine:

```
http://localhost:8880/myapp/getAlertFilterHistory/null/null/?_=1448024656575
```

Also when I pass the encoded dates as query string, it works.

```
http://localhost:8880/myapp/validateFilterHistoryDates?filterStartDate=2015%252F11%252F01%252018%253A38&filterEndDate=2015%252F11%252F09%252018%253A38
```

So the encode dates works when I pass them as query string but fails when I pass them as path variables.

> My Java code in Spring Controller is:

```
@RequestMapping("getAlertFilterHistory/{fromDateStr}/{toDateStr}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getAlertFilterHistory(@PathVariable String fromDateStr, @PathVariable String toDateStr, HttpSession session) {
}
```

> My javascript call:

```
var filterStartDate = encodeURIComponent($('#filterStartDate').val());
var filterEndDate = encodeURIComponent($('#filterEndDate').val());

var filterHistortTable = $('#filterConfigurationsTable').DataTable();   
//Clear the datatable
filterHistortTable.clear().draw();
filterHistortTable.ajax.url('getAlertFilterHistory/'+filterStartDate+'/'+filterEndDate+'/').load();
//filterHistortTable.ajax.url('getAlertFilterHistory/null/null/').load(); // this works
```

> My datatable code in javascript

```
var filterConfigurationsDataTable = $('#filterConfigurationsTable').dataTable( {
                    "sAjaxSource" : 'getAlertFilterHistory/null/null/',                 
                    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap", 
                    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                    "bRetrieve": true,
                    "bProcessing": true,                                        
                    "aoColumns": [
                        { "data": "requestDate" },
                        { "data": "requestType" },
                        { "data": "applicationNames" },
                        { "data": "hosts" },
                        { "data": "matchStrings" },
                        { "data": "regEx" },
                        { "data": "activationTime" },
                        { "data": "expirationTime" },
                        { "data": "modifiedBy" },
                        { "data": "ticket" },
                        { "data": "api"},
                        { "data": "description"}

                    ] ,                 
                    "scrollX": true
                } );
```

Does anyone knows why this is happening?

**EDIT**:

I still don't know why it is happening, I changed my code to accept query string instead of uri path and it worked.

I changed in jsp:

```
//filterHistortTable.ajax.url('getAlertFilterHistory/'+filterStartDate+'/'+filterEndDate+'/').load();
filterHistortTable.ajax.url('getAlertFilterHistory?fromDateStr='+filterStartDate+'&toDateStr='+filterEndDate).load();
```

and in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAlertFilterHistory", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getAlertFilterHistory(@RequestParam(value = "fromDateStr", required = false) String fromDateStr,
            @RequestParam(value = "toDateStr", required = false) String toDateStr, HttpSession session) {
    //(@PathVariable String fromDateStr, @PathVariable String toDateStr, HttpSession session) {
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to put filtering into path. Use parameters. Pat for resource

Comment: I can use a post request and it won't need encoding. But I want to do a Get as I am just fetching data to display.

Comment: How you are sending the request to server, using Ajax or some scripting mechanism ?? Try to set the `Content-type` in the request as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8` ..

Comment: Set following in your Ajax request `setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");`

Comment: Did you give a try  ??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact problem since it looks fine by decoding the values. But as a developer, I think this is not the professional way to send DATETIME values in the URL. You have to send them in a simple way like Timestamp, then remap them in your business logic layer into actual Datetime objects.